# ACS50001 Relying party with identifier was not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, single-sign-on, federation

I am trying to have Azure federation in one of my MVC application, but ending up having this error

Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in.

Account 'soandso@microsoft.com' is not configured to sign-in to this application.

Sign-out and sign-in with another account.

Additional technical information:
Trace ID: b94e380f-8234-4221-a59d-6efb5e644c83
Timestamp: 2014-06-25 08:35:00Z
ACS50001: ACS50001: Relying party with identifier 'http://testsmb.azurewebsites.net/testsmb' was not found

Not sure where I am doing wrong. Any help would be highly appreciated. I tried doing googling but nothing helps.

Vinod

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running the browser in in-private mode? It looks like you are signing in automatically to the microsoft.com directory, whereas you want to use a test directory for your development.

Azure AD does not issue a token to an application if the application hasn't been installed in the directory. The installation of the application can happen in two modes: Administrator consent and User only consent. With administrator consent, the application can sign-in any user in the organization, however with user only consent, the application can sign-in only that specific user. This help topic (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151789.aspx) explains how to get consent in the 'Add Sign-Up Capabilities to the Application' section.

Comment: Yes it didn't work. It works fine with test directory while when I try to run it in Microsoft domain it doesn't work

Comment: Ah! I see. Azure AD does not issue a token to an application if the application hasn't been installed in the directory. The installation of the application can happen in two modes: Administrator consent and User only consent. With administrator consent, the application can sign-in any user in the organization, however with user only consent, the application can sign-in only that specific user. This help topic (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151789.aspx) explains how to get consent in the 'Add Sign-Up Capabilities to the Application' section.

Comment: I have already followed this document and it works fine with my test directory. But doesn't work with Microsoft AD. I can show you this in a screen sharing(if you wish) the issue...This issue is really holding a project of us for sign off..

Comment: Indeed. Lets get in touch. I'd like to look at a fiddler trace. Can you send me your contact email on http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/contact/ ? Thanks

Comment: I have sent you my email-vinod8812@gmail.com